# Pointing sub.domain to remote server and assigning DNS

Tags: domains

I've created a CNAME record for sub.domain.com on Site5 pointing to the main domain of an account on BlueHost.

On BlueHost I assigned domain.com using the .html verification method and created sub.domain.com - but it isn't working :(

I'm not sure how to navigate this between these two hosting environments. Support seemed to know less than I do. My FIRST attempt was to create an A record and assign the sub.domain but that didn't work.

How can I point a sub.domain correctly and map it on the receiving end so it's pointing to a directory on my shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

I had to wait for it to propagate, that was it... This works exactly as expected!

> I've created a CNAME record for sub.domain.com on Site5 pointing to the main domain of an account on BlueHost.
>
> On BlueHost I assigned domain.com using the .html verification method and created sub.domain.com

**It is working!**